# bash script in OS X to copy all .wavs

Tags: bash, macos, quoting, glob

I've been attempting to copy all `.wav` files on my system (OS X based) into one folder .. strangely nothing is getting copied into the new folder.

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name /Applications/*.wav -exec cp {} /Users/myhouse/Downloads/audio_pool/wav/ ;
```

is there a risk of getting a loop going (ie it finds files and continues to just copy them into the folder)

I also tried this format

```
for f in /*.wav; do cp "$f" /Users/myhouse/Downloads/audio_pool/wav/.; done
```

Comment: What about `cp *.wav /Users/myhouse/Downloads/audio_pool/wav/`? Or is the idea that you'll get all wav files recursively from the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob needs to be escaped to have `find` interpret it rather than the shell. Move the `/Applications/` path to the front: `-name` is only matching the file name, not the full path. Make sure to quote the `;` at the end, too.

```
find /Applications/ -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} /Users/myhouse/Downloads/audio_pool/wav/ ';'
```

```
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^                                                      ^^^
       directory        quoted glob                                                  quoted
```